# How to truncate a string in shell script using sed or regular expression?

Tags: regex, string, shell, sed

I have a string that reads like `" siva:x:503:505::/home/abc:/bin/bash "`.
 I want to store only `503` in a variable. how to achieve that using regular expression or sed command. or is it possible any other way?

Comment: What have you tried, what doesn't work?

Comment: bash, powershell, ksh, zsh, csh, other?

Comment: `grep -oP '.*?:.*?:\K.*?(?=:)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `cut`:

```
myvar=$(echo "siva:x:50ds3:505::/home/abc:/bin/bash" | cut -d':' -f3);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to store only **503** in a variable

Use one the following approaches:

- `sed` command with specific regex pattern:

  ```
  number=$(echo " siva:x:503:505::/home/abc:/bin/bash " | sed -rn 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/gp')
  ```

  `([0-9]+)` - will capture the first sequence of digits
- `awk` command with field separator specified by regex pattern `[^0-9]*`:

  ```
  number=$(echo " siva:x:503:505::/home/abc:/bin/bash " | awk -F"[^0-9]*" '{print $2}')
  ```

  `-F"[^0-9]*"` - sequence of non-digits is considered as the field separator(to access all numbers via field numbers)

---

```
echo $number
```

The output:

```
503
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk -F":" '{print $3}'`

```
bash-4.2$  echo " siva:x:503:505::/home/abc:/bin/bash "|awk -F":" '{print $3}'
503
```

Comment: Thanx Mate! Worked very well :)